# Find partial derivative of composite function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to find the partial derivative of composite function  $ F(F(x,y), y)$. I will denote $  G= F(F(x,y), y) =F(f, g) $, where  $f = F(x,y)$, $g=y$. My attempt to calculate $ \frac{\partial^2 G}{ \partial x^2}$  at point $(x_0, y_0)$ is:

$$    \frac{\partial ^2 G}{ \partial x^2}(x_0, y_0)=  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x} \left( \frac{\partial G}{ \partial x} \right) =  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x}   \left(   \frac{\partial G}{ \partial f}  \frac{\partial F}{ \partial x}  \right )    $$
I am not sure how to proceed, could someone write the whole solution? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the variable $y$ isn't playing much of a role here, so it might be easier to see the answer for a function of a single variable: what is $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(f(x))$? Let's start by computing the first derivative via the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\left[f(f(x))\right]
    = f'(f(x))\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)\right]
    = f'(f(x))f'(x).
\end{align*}
Now the second derivative will require the product rule:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left[f(f(x))\right]
    &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[f'(f(x))f'(x)\right]
    \\
    &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[f'(f(x))\right]f'(x) + f'(f(x))\frac{d}{dx}\left[f'(x)\right]
    \\
    &= f''(f(x))\frac{d}{dx}\left[f(x)\right]f'(x) + f'(f(x))\frac{d}{dx}\left[f'(x)\right]
    \\
    &= f''(f(x))f'(x)^{2} + f'(f(x))f''(x).
\end{align*}

Now back to the original multivariate problem. Let's try to write out the first derivative without any substitutions.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F(F(x,y),y)\right]
= F_{x}(F(x,y),y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F(x,y)\right]
= F_{x}(F(x,y),y)F_{x}(x,y).
$$
For the second derivative we need the product rule, but this is still straightforward if we can keep track of everything.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\left[F(F(x,y),y)\right]
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F_{x}(F(x,y),y)F_{x}(x,y)\right]
    \\
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F_{x}(F(x,y),y)\right]F_{x}(x,y) + F_{x}(F(x,y),y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[F_{x}(x,y)\right]
    \\
    &= F_{xx}(F(x,y),y)F_{x}(x,y)F_{x}(x,y) + F_{x}(F(x,y),y)F_{xx}(x,y)
    \\
    &= F_{xx}(F(x,y),y)F_{x}(x,y)^{2} + F_{x}(F(x,y),y)F_{xx}(x,y).
\end{align*}
Evaluated at a point $(x_0, y_0)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\left[F(F(x,y),y)\right]\big|_{(x_0,y_0)}
    = F_{xx}(F(x_{0},y_{0}),y_{0})F_{x}(x_0,y_0)^{2} + F_{x}(F(x_0,y_0),y_0)F_{xx}(x_0,y_0).
\end{align*}